# Postgres flyway create concurrently index error

Tags: java, postgresql, flyway, postgresql-9.2

I want do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __column_exists(TEXT, TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS bool as $$
SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns WHERE (table_schema, table_name, column_name) = ($1, $2, $3));
$$ language sql STRICT;

DO $$ BEGIN IF __column_exists('public', 'table_name', 'column_name') THEN
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS column_idx ON table_name USING btree (column_name);
END IF; END; $$;
```

But there is

> ERROR: CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY cannot run inside a transaction block

It works fine if I write only

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS column_idx ON table_name USING btree (column_name);
```

How can I preserve the condition for the existence of a column?

Flyway 4.2.0;

Comment: IIRC, you need to use two separate scripts (that is `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` must be on its own in a script, otherwise Flyway can't run it without transaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using such an old version of flyway ?
You should first upgrade your version of flyway, and then:

Create a configuration file for your script like V01_001__my_script.sql.conf
where V01_001__my_script.sql is the name of your sql file.

and put this line inside:

```
executeInTransaction=false
```

That will disable the execution in a transaction for this script.

Comment: There is a lot of old legacy code)
When i started updating the version it caused a cascade of errors.
Tomorrow i will try your advice)

Comment: There is new problem) Postgres cant run functions and procedure in non transactional mode